# I want to create Audio calling App in android studio with FCM is it possible

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a simple chat application, but it requires Voice calls functionality to other users. I would be using Firebase for messaging. Does Firebase have Voice calls support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WebRTC for Audio call and use FCM for signaling. But Firebase as a service does not provide any support for Audio/Video calls. You can also use third party SDKs like Twilio.

Answer (score 1):

no firebase does not support voice call support. It is support service like push notification using FCM.

Comment: Please doc. of firebase

Comment: @SourabhPatil, documentation contains only what it **does support**, no what it **does not**.

Comment: @amit thnx for help

Answer (score 1):

FCM is for push notifications. Previously there was GCM, but it is deprecated now. But it is not used for video calls, the only thing you can do is to send push notification to user, when someone calls him. To manage calls you need to use something like WebRTC.
You should try [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/) provider. They have [Android SDK](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/) for chat/video calls and offer code samples, so that you can use them as basis for your project. It is WebRTC based and works pretty stable on my experience.
Check the list of the main features for video calls on ConnectyCube [page](https://connectycube.com/features/)